# $\pi_*:Ho(Top_*)\to Set^{\mathbb N}$ preserves limits

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits, model-categories

Consider $\pi_*:Ho(Top_*)\to Set^{\mathbb N}$ defined by $[X,x]\mapsto \{\pi_n(X,x)\}_n$ from the homotopy category of the pointed topological spaces. I showed that this is a conservative functor and I want to show that it preserves limits.

So let $\{f_j:[X,x]\to [Y_j,y_j]\}$ be a limit in $Ho(Top_*)$, we have that $f_j$ can be written as the homotopy class of some $f_j^{cf}:(X,x)^{cf}\to (Y_j,y_j)^{cf}$ where we replace $X,Y_j$ by bifibrant replacements.

Now we get that $\{\pi_*(f_j):\{\pi_n(X,x)\}\to\{\pi_n(Y_j,y_j)\}\}$ satisfy the cone condition, the problem is to show the universal property.

So suppose $\{q_j:\{S_n\}\to \{\pi_n(Y_j,y_j)\}\}$ satisfies the cone condition, I guess the idea is to use the fact that $[X,x]$ is a limit but I don't know how to do it. Is it a left/right adjoint ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't recall if $\operatorname{Ho}{\mathrm{Top}_*}$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Top}_*$ modulo homotopy but in case it is, then replacing the domain and using the fact each $\pi_i$ is representable and limits in the codomain are computed pointwise, the result follows.

Comment: @interregno I think it isn't for arbitrary spaces, but for a cofibrant object $A$ such as the spheres and a fibrant object $X$ (any space is fibrant) the identification $\operatorname{HoTop}_\ast(A,X) = \operatorname{Top}_\ast(A,X)/\text{htpy}$ holds anyway, so you can make the argument.

Comment: @JonasLinssen Yes you're right. I guess we could use that one fundamental equivalence from model category theory too. Deleted my previous comment because I recalled that the categorical equivalence I had in mind held only localizing w.r.t. homotopy equivalencies.

Comment: @interregno I don't know about representable functors, What exactly are we replacing here ? I'm not sure to see what the argument is, what does the fact that $\pi_n$ is representable induce ?

Comment: @raisinsec We call a functor representable when it is naturally isomorphic to a functor of the form $\operatorname{Hom}{(X, \_)} = y(X)$. By definition the $\pi_n$ are representable functors in the category modulo homotopy, hence why I propose the change of domain. It is a standard theorem of category theory that $y(X)$ preserves limits, so any representable functor does. Moreover, a limit in $\mathrm{Set}^\mathbb{N}$ is computed separately on each coordinate of the product.

Comment: @interregno So if I understand, the fact that each $\pi_n$ is preserves limit and that the limit in Set$^{\mathbb N}$ is computed on coordinates enables us to replace $\{\pi_n(X,x)\},\{pi_n(Y_j,y_j)\}$ by just $(X,x)$ $(Y_j,y_j)$  and to show it's a limit. But since we have that this is a limit by assumption, their images by $\pi_n$ gives a limit in Set^{\mathbb N} am I right ?